# Not able to fix TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
```

Exception, I have tried most of the options present in the StackOverflow, but still, this error occurs, will you tell me if I am doing something wrong? Here is my code:

Application Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.gide.iis.bls" })
public class ServerCoreApiApplication {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Application starting.........");
        context = SpringApplication.run(ServerCoreApiApplication.class, args);
        Bls s = (Bls) context.getBean("bls");
        s.start();
        System.out.println("Application started...");
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatchServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        return dispatchServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> servRegBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>();
        servRegBean.setServlet(dispatcherServlet());
        servRegBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servRegBean.addUrlMappings("/service/*");

        return servRegBean;
    }

}
```

Service and Repository classes are present in another project, which I included in Spring Boot app and written Configuration files to create beans for them:

Service Class:

```
@Transactional
public class LoggingService implements ILoggingService {
. //Some code
.
.
    @Transactional
    public final LogMessage createLogMessage( final LogMessage pLogMessage ) throws LoggingException {
      ..
      .. //Some Code.
      logMessageRepository.persist(logMessageEntity); //Calling persist of repository.
   }
}
```

My Log Message Repository class is extending one abstract class called JpaGenericRepository which implements that persist method, but it's present in jar, 
Abstract Class persist method is:

```
@Override
    public E persist(final E pEntity) throws RepositoryException {
        CheckArg.notNull("pEntity", pEntity);
        System.out.println("Entity hash Code: " + entityManager.hashCode());
        entityManager.persist(pEntity);


        entityManager.flush();
        return pEntity;
    }
```

Entity Manager is declared in the abstract class as:

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

I have tried multiple options with @Transactional, @EnableTransactionManagement, and few others, but failed.
Please help. Ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: have you tried the way [this](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring) suggests?

Comment: Check if you have all the required elements on classpath to autoconfigure transactions. Maybe you have excluded some configuration classes by setting spring.autoconfigure.exclude property or something?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have checked all the configurations there is no  spring.autoconfigure.exclude present. I have searched in dependent projects also.